# Declaração de variáveis Java

Tags: java, variáveis, desempenho, declaração-de-variável

Existe alguma diferença entre as duas declarações:

Primeira:

```
int a;
int b;
```

Segunda:

```
int a, b;
```

Qual a melhor? As variáveis ficam mais próximas na memória ou isso é apenas mito? Existe alguma diferença significativa?

Comment: Creio que não haja diferença alguma, só legibilidade apenas, a primeira forma vai ocupar uma linha a mais, mas é mais legível, dependendo da quantidade de variáveis decladadas no código.

Comment: A forma de declarar não interfere no desempenho, já a forma de inicializar pode interferir bastante (https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não, zero, isso é só uma de forma de sintaxe. Depois de compilado é tudo igual. De forma geral todas essas formas diferentes de sintaxe não mudam nada. Poderia haver quando há diferença semântica, o que não é o caso, não existe isso de ficar mais próximo na memória, você não tem controle disso e mesmo que ocorresse não faria diferença porque a memória é acessada de forma direta e muda nada onde está (de forma geral, existem casos bem mais complexos que isso pode mudar, mas é algo muito avançado mesmo, não para coisas simples assim.

Note que não tem contexto na pergunta. Faz diferença mais pelo contexto usado do que isto em si. Não isso, mas faz diferença se isso é variável local ou membro de um objeto. Não que importe tanto a variável nesse caso.

Por isso é importante entender cada detalhe do código. Costumo usar essa frase nas minhas palestras:

[image: Enquanto você não souber o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "é importante entender cada detalhe do código" - Há quem prefira gastar o tempo em juntar retalhos de código encontrado na net, e depois vir perguntar como corrigir os erros decorrentes do copy/paste, em vez de o usar a aprender a linguagem e as bases da programação. Eu, quando quis fazer algo para Android, antes de escrever uma linha de código, "gastei" mais de um mês a ler a documentação e a ver tutoriais. Isso, apesar de já ter experiência em programação noutras plataformas.

Comment: Sim, deve ser desta forma, entender os conceitos, verificar se já tem todos os requisitos para este novo aprendizado, começar estudar de forma estruturada, até tirar dúvidas com outras pessoas quando necessário, começar treinar com coisas simples, autocontidas, e ir avançando, até que chega no ponto de entender para trabalhar seriamente. E aí quase não terá perguntas, sim respostas para dar ;)

Answer (score 0):

Em termos de desempenho não muda nada, se você está fazendo o programa sozinho também não muda nada.
Se você está desenvolvendo um software como funcionário de uma empresa ou em equipe utilize a forma com o qual a empresa ou equipe decidiu padronizar, pois facilita a identação e leitura do código.
Procure ter noções gerais de como um compilador funciona, saber como um software compila irá te tornar um programador melhor.

Answer (score -1):

> Qual a melhor?

Nenhuma das duas muda nada, a melhor escolha é aquela em que você se sente mais confortável em usar e que as pessoas consigam entender. Pois o código nos escrevemos para que os outros possam ler posteriormente.

> As variáveis ficam mais próximas na memória ou isso é apenas mito?

Creio que seja mito.

> Existe alguma diferença significativa?

Não existe nenhuma diferença, as duas estão certas e compilam tranquilamente!

Espero ter te ajudado